# adding items to actionbar correctly

Tags: android, xml

I need help figuring the right way to control the actionbar.

At the onCreate function i added:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

And added actionbar.xml to the layout folder with 3 items in it: TextView (app name) and 2 ImageViews.

It works, i mean i can see this new actionbar, but i'm pretty sure i'm doing it the wrong way, in tutorials im reading they're talking about adding those items to a menu.xml file which i couldn't find, and using onOptionsItemSelected function to set the behaviour.

As I'm a begginer, would appreciate an explanation of what it is that i'm doing, why it's wrong and how to do it correctly with the menu.xml

Comment: You're talking about two separate things. The menu.xml file is for menu items, which show on the right side of the ActionBar.

Comment: @DanielNugent is right, I mean you're merging two different things

Comment: well my goal is to adjust the actionbar, because my phone language is right-to-left i found a solution by creating this actionbar.xml and specify the layoutDirection, now i want to add buttons to it but obviously did it wrong. i hope it clarifies what i'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first you are right, Android have an out of the box solution to put "Action Button" and Title on the Action Bar

1.Title

When you create an Activity, it will add some code into your AndroidManifest.xml, here is the example:

```
 <activity
        android:name="AddAddressActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_address" >
    </activity>
```

so you change your title here by changing android:label, the best practice is you need to put all your string asset under res/values/string.xml like this

```
<string name="title_activity_add_address">Add New Address</string>
```

2. Action Button

First add this override method to your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.address_list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Later, you create address_list.xml under res/menu folder, and inside it you can put the list of your Action Button there

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.vi8e.giant.AddressListActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:title="@string/action_save"/>
```

Android:title is to put your menu title, this title will show up when you long press the menu
Android:icon here is the image that you want to show for the menu, put the image under res/drawable

Edit: forgot to mention about how to trigger your menu
you can put onOptionsItemSelected method on your Activity, here is the example

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_add:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

note: Action Bar has a limited ammount of space, so if you have a lot of menu, it will be collapse into "three dots" icon on the top-right corner

Comment: Thanks Richard for the detailed answer, it works but with one problem - in the actionbar.xml i made, i could add - android:layoutDirection="ltr", because my phone shows everything "rtl", in this new menu.xml file i can't add this (i can but it does nothing) and all the icons shows in those "three dots". how can i fix this?

Comment: ok i changed android:supportsRtl="true" to android:supportsRtl="false"
and now it's left-to-right but all the items are still in the 3 dots (even if i use only 1 items, so there's room) why is this happening?

Comment: ok thanks i fixed it. just changed - android:supportsRtl="true" to android:supportsRtl="false" in AndroidManfiest.xml under "<application",
and changed in menu.xml  - android:showAsAction="always" to app:showAsAction="always", now its working. Thanks again!

Comment: great! glad I could help. Please mark it as answer if it's help :)